# While sending notification by tapping a button, the crash gets occur

Tags: ios, swift, dispatch-async

I am facing the crash

> Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.

I referred to the crash and added the line `self.Indicator.stopAnimating()` in my code. It runs fine for one or two tests, and it shows the same crash again.

Comment: You're performing UI action on main thread need to do it in async block.

Comment: it just because your code is already running in main thread so you just need to do that async : DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    print("This is run on the background queue")

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("This is run on the main queue, after the previous code in outer block")
    }
}

Comment: Do not change UI from anything but the main thread. While it may appear to work on some OS or devices and not others, it is bound to make your application unstable, and crash unpredictably.

If you must respond to a notification, which can happen in the background, then ensure UIKit invocation takes place on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

All the UI handling must be done on the ***main thread*** instead of the *background thread*. That's what the crash says.

So move your UI specific code to `DispatchQueue.main.async`, i.e.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self?.Indicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

That stands for all the UI specific changes. Move them to main thread.

*Unrelated*: use **camel-casing** for variable names. It must be `indicator` instead of `Indicator`.

Comment: Hi @PGDev thanks for the answer. But already am using this like `DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                            if imageData != nil
                            {
                                if UIImage(data:imageData) != nil
                                {
                                    //Storing the image in the cache
                                 .............
                                    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                                }
                            }
                        })`

Comment: Have you tried putting an exception breakpoint and checking where exactly the app crashed?